# How to open Picker on TextInput in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, picker

I am learning React Native and I am trying to open Picker on TextInput instead of Keyboard. But, It's not working. Here is my code:

```
_renderData(item, index) {
    {item.fieldName == 'State' ? this._renderPicker() : this._renderTextInput(item, index)}
}

_renderTextInput(item, index){
    return (
        <TextInput
            style={registrationStyles.textInput}
            keyboardType={item.keyboardType}
            maxLength={item.max}
            placeholder={item.placeholder}
            onChangeText={text => {this._setValueToJson(text, index, item)}} />
    )
}

_renderPicker() {
    return (
            <Picker
                selectedValue={this.state.language}
                style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ language: itemValue })}>
                {this.props.loginSuccess.result.map((item, index) => {
                 return (<Picker.Item label={item.state_name} value={index} key={index}/>) 
                })}
            </Picker>
    )
 }
```

Here, I am getting a list of Data from API and I am trying to show it in Picker. How is that possible? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Follow below link, you can manage accordingly.

[react-native-select-input-ios](https://github.com/markuswind/react-native-select-input-ios)